# Installing Sitecore 9, SIF Error on installing SOLR cores

Tags: sitecore, sitecore9

When installing Sitecore with SIF, I experiencing the following error.

[image]

These are my modules

[image]

who can help thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A while ago, we encountered this issue too. After some research we found out that the casing of the parameter "name" didn't match between the installer scripts and the configuration files (The scripts used "**name**" while the config files mentioned "**Name**"). After renaming the parameter in the config files, the installation process could continue.

**sitecore-solr.json**
[image: sitecore-solr.json]

**xconnect-solr.json**
[image: xconnect-solr.json]

Answer (score 2):

For Sitecore 9.0 (update-x) you need SIF 1.2.1,
Since you already have a newer SIF version, it will uses the latest version and fail.

You can add this on the top of your PowerShell script to force use the 1.2.1 version:

```
Remove-Module -Name SitecoreInstallFramework
Import-Module -Name SitecoreInstallFramework -RequiredVersion 1.2.1
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Note: If you have already before installed Sitecore with higher SIF version, then you are probably running into a certificate issue when you fix the wrong SIF version error. See [Sitecore XP 9.0 Update-2 installation fails when XP 9.1 is installed on the same PC](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/699694)
or you can delete the other Sitecore certificates if you don't need them, (Personal and Trusted Root Certification Authorities) with certmgr 
or with PowerShell:

```
Set-Location Cert:\LocalMachine\Root
#get a list
Get-ChildItem | Format-Table FriendlyName, Thumbprint -AutoSize

#example of remove a certificate
Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\Root\301F9A11F82BF45DA853BE573811AFF4ACA3B7CE | Remove-Item
```

Because your installation failed, it is also possible you have already created a certificates with precisely the same DNS name as the installer try to create than you also need to delete the old not in use certificate.